# unique( and other numpy functions) on timezone naive pandas columns convert to local timezone

Tags: numpy, pandas, timezone

I am not quite clear whether this is a numpy bug a pandas bug or my user error.
Could anyone provide clarification...
My work around is to use strings to do the unique, but I am constantly running into these problems...and would value suggested working practise ( eg always set UTC?)

So I would expect unique to return a naïve datetime rather than interpret as local ...

```
import pandas as pd
d=pd.DataFrame({'a':['2014-10-12','2014-10-11']})
d['b']=pd.to_datetime(d.a)
print d
print d['b'].unique()
print d['b'].max()
print d['b'].values.max()

        a          b
0  2014-10-12 2014-10-12
1  2014-10-11 2014-10-11

['2014-10-12T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2014-10-11T02:00:00.000000000+0200'] #unique

2014-10-12 00:00:00 # pandas max

2014-10-12T02:00:00.000000000+0200  #numpy max
```

numpy '1.9.2'
pandas '0.16.1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all the same date/time, but the functions are returning different types, with different string representations (i.e. different `__str__` and `__repr__` output).

`d['b'].unique()` and `d['b'].values.max()` are returning `numpy.datetime64` objects, while `d['b'].max()` is returning a `pandas.Timestamp` object. `numpy.datetime64` uses the system's locale to set timezone when it is outputted as a string while `pandas.Timestamp` does not.

If you convert the `pandas.Timestamp` to `numpy.datetime64` you will see that they are the same value:

```
np.datetime64(d['b'].max().to_datetime()) == d['b'].values.max()
```

Comment: I accept your answer -but I don't think I agree with your 'proof'. My question was whether a timezone naïve object was being converted into a local timezone object.